# Possible to access config variables from a parallel application within Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have two Codeigniter applications that share the same CI installation. They each have their own set of config files.

I'm wondering whether it is possible to access a config variable in App A from App B (and vice versa).

Why? To try and avoid repetition and errors when variables have to be changed in multiple places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can access variables from another application.
However, maybe you could try creating a php file - reachable from both applications - where you define those variables you want to be mutual.

Then, you can call the php file from each config file and assign the values.